# Prime ideals and powers of elements...

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity, and let $a$ be an element of $R$. Let $M$ be an ideal of $R$ s.t.:
>
> 1) $a^n$ is not in $M$ for all $n$.
>
> 2) Whenever we find an ideal $K$ such that $M$ is a proper subset of $K$, there exists a power of $a$ in $K.$
>
> Prove that $M$ is prime.

The problem itself states that we are to show that if $xy\in M$, then $x\in M$ or $y\in M$.

Comment: Don't you mean that $K$ is a proper subset of $M$?

Comment: No...if that were true then the power of a would be in M.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking "superset" instead of "subset".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $M$ is not prime.  Then there is some $x,y \in R$ such that $xy \in M$ but neither $x$ nor $y$ is in $M$.  By hypothesis, both ideals $(M,x)$ and $(M,y)$ contain a power of $a$, since they properly contain $M$, and therefore, so does their product.  But their product is contained in $M$ (since $xy \in M$), and therefore $M$ contains a power of $a$.  Contradiction.

The same argument holds if the set of powers of $a$ is replaced by any multiplicatively closed subset of $R$.